# OSX Lion - missing csrutil command

Tags: terminal, macos, windows

i have IMac 5,1 with Lion 10.7.5 OSX and in terminal i'm trying to use the command csrutil.
I checked everywhere but didn't find the way to have and use it.
The reason is that i would like to disable ( i know i have to do in recovery mode) to install windows 7 32bit( 64bit seems not possible)
Last week i upgrade the HD to SSD of 1TB and RAM from 2 to 4gb and i used CarbonCopyCloner to clone the OSX but i lost the Windows partition that i would like to have again.
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: You Mac may be able to run 64 bit Windows 7 or 64 bit Windows 10. The only way to know if the Boot Camp drivers provided by Apple will work with 64 bit Windows is to try installing them. If interested, post a comment.

Comment: If my answer below was correct, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `csrutil` command in macOS 10.7.

System Integrity Protection (SIP) was introduced in macOS 10.11, and the `csrutil` command is for modifying SIP.

More at [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) about SIP in macOS 10.11 and later.

Comment: thank you so much so i don't need to disable it to install windows